# Puppeteer script suddenly stopped working after upgrading Puppeteer

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer script I run to reboot my modem. It has worked for I guess about a year with no problem. 5 days ago it stopped working. I was looking into it and realized that I am getting errors I didn't used to get when running it and the script fails. The thing is I didn't change anything. As far as I can see, the HTML hasn't changed either yet it is failing. So I wonder if there is a bug in chromium or puppeteer or if it handles things differently somehow?

Here's a codepen with https://codepen.io/michaelbierman/pen/qQjdYR

1. HTML page
2. puppeteer script

errors

```
ERROR OUTPUT
```

Thursday 11/15/2018 11:14:04,  Login...
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise (new page) Promise {
   Error: No node found for selector: #id_username
    at assert (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.type (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:771:5)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame. (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.type (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:971:29)
    at /Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:49:13
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) } reason: Error: No node found for selector: #id_username
    at assert (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.type (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:771:5)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame. (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.type (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:971:29)
    at /Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:49:13
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:29
    browser.close();
    ^

ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at process.on (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:29:2)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:108:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
BigMac:bin michael$ /usr/local/bin/node /Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js
Thursday 11/15/2018 11:20:29,  Login...
Thursday 11/15/2018 11:20:36,  Go to home...
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise (new page) Promise {
   Error: No node found for selector: #alertExitButton
    at assert (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.click (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:704:5)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame. (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.click (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:932:29)
    at /Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:62:13
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) } reason: Error: No node found for selector: #alertExitButton
    at assert (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:278:11)
    at Frame.click (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:704:5)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame. (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.click (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:932:29)
    at /Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:62:13
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:29
    browser.close();
    ^

ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at process.on (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/arristest.js:29:2)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:108:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

Comment: Might sound a bit obvious but if you've upgraded your `puppeteer` version and are seeing this only after the upgrade, have you tried deleting your `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` file and then re-installing your project dependencies (including the updated version of `puppeteer`) from scratch using `npm install`? Can often clear up strange errors like this.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent suggestion.  I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: Let me know how you get on. Will try and work with you on this issue if it's still coming up.

Comment: I deleted the files you specified and reinstalled. I got a few errors along the way, but things seem to be working better. I don't know if I should be concerned about these errors

https://pastebin.com/R48Nrv44

Comment: Looks like node doesn't have some permissions that it needs. I've had this on my Mac and had to manually change the node directory to my users home directory to resolve it. EIther way the node docs can help (hopefully). You should have a look here to try and resolve your issue: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall chromium
npm uninstall puppeteer
npm i chromium@1
npm i puppeteer
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you write a bit about your suggestion, doesn't have to be much, just enough to explain what you're doing and why you think it solves the problem, so that any future reader can understand your solution easily. Also, you might want to take a look at [answer] for more input on writing good answers.