# Executing Puppeteer from PHP suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, exec

We had not done any recent upgrades.

We are trying to run this javascript code (createpdf.js)

```
    const puppeteer = require('/home/glossyadmin/node_modules/puppeteer');
    const InvoiceNumber = process.argv[2];
    const PDFdir = __dirname + '/../email/invoice/';

    (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:8080/admin/ajax/invoice?InvoiceNumber=' + InvoiceNumber + '&Print=Print', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

   await page.pdf({path: PDFdir + InvoiceNumber + '.pdf', format: 'A4'});
   await browser.close();
    })();
```

We have been calling the code above with this PHP script:

```
$Vars = json_decode(urldecode(@$argv[1]), true);
$InvoiceNumber = $Vars['InvoiceNumber'];
$createScript = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/workers/createpdf.js';
exec("node $createScript 2>&1 ".escapeshellarg($InvoiceNumber), $arrayReturn);
```

It has been working but lately it just stopped.  The code seems good (no PHP errors in the error log) but it just is no longer calling / executing the createpdf.js script.   And we have verified that node is in fact installed.

We have not upgraded PHP, Node, or any other updates. We've tried changing permissions of files and directories.  Nothing changes. Slamming our head into a wall here.

Comment: No node errors in the node log?

Comment: We are running node within Apache so we don’t have specific node logs. As far as I’m aware. And no other node specific errors show up in the Apache2/error.log

Comment: Node has a console output

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to dig and finding out more and more people were having this issue with little to no fixes.  I found another thread on stackoverflow that talked about somebody that had upgraded their version of puppeteer and it suddenly stopped working.

We had not done any upgrades to puppeteer, node, or the system at all but still wasn't working.  I took the very simple advice in the comments of this thread: [Puppeteer script suddenly stopped working after upgrading Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326770/puppeteer-script-suddenly-stopped-working-after-upgrading-puppeteer)

Delete the entire node_modules directory and reinstall puppeteer.
Not sure why exactly but it has worked.  I wish there was more information out there.  Luckily it's a quick install.